Why I get an error while importing Selenium Webdriver
I am trying to run selenium on a raspberry with debian_version 11.8 and os-release Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).
Python version is Python 3.9.2 installed with venv to ../bin/python3.
Chrome is installed to the rpi with sudo apt install rpi-chromium-mods
I installed selenium with python3 -m pip install selenium without errors.
I downloaded the chromedriver, chmod +x chromedriver, put it in .myapp/bin and .myapp directory.
I installed  chromium-chromedriver with sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver(was it necessary? I googled it and I tried it)
I have appended the bin path that has the chromedriver to .bashrc
export PATH="/home/pi/myapp/.myapp/bin:$PATH"
By the way tried and installed conda instead of venv, to see if it does any difference, but it perplexed things even more (it downgraded python to 3.4 and i couldn't upgrade again, I got all shorts of other problems) so I uninstalled it.
Common problem after i run python code is the following:

Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import selenium
>>> from selenium import webdriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/myapp/.myapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .chrome.webdriver import WebDriver as Chrome  # noqa
  File "/home/pi/myapp/.myapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 18, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.chromium.webdriver import ChromiumDriver
  File "/home/pi/myapp/.myapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 22, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "/home/pi/myapp/.myapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 57, in <module>
    from ..common.fedcm.dialog import Dialog
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.common.fedcm'
>>> 

By running which selenium or whereis selenium with active or inactive venv I get nothing. But when looking into the ../lib/python3.9/site-packages I see selenium and other libraries in place. After this I added the /home/pi/myapp/.myapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages explicitly to the path. Now when I issue whereis selenium I get selenium: /home/pi/myapp/.myapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium. However the error stays.
Is it a path thing, unsuccessful installation, environment problem? Why does the import selenium works and not the from selenium import webdriver Any suggestions? Something I am missing?
Edit:
I kept getting all short of errors and I decided to install ubuntu. I created an environment and I installed sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver and pip3 install selenium . I was still getting mainly two errors: chromium-browser/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed. and Unsupported platform/architecture combination: linux/armv7l. Finally I uninstalled selenium and installed specific version as suggected below by @stapmoshun. pip3 install selenium==4.26.1
The simple code below runs without error:
import platform       
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
# a few usefull options
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--headless") # if you want it headless

if platform.system() == "Linux" and platform.machine() == "armv7l":  
    # if raspi
    options.BinaryLocation = ("/usr/bin/chromium-browser")
    service = Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
else: # if not raspi and considering you're using Chrome
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())           

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=service,
    options=options
    )
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79264531/why-i-get-an-error-while-importing-selenium-webdriver'
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
#finish 
driver.quit()


I uninstalled the myapp in the environment and reinstalled, I added a new app in venv but again I had no luck. I further deleted everything and I installed the app system wide, deleting also any $PATH additions.  I also installed selenium system wide with pip install selenium. Now the line with from selenium import webdriver doesn't create problems. Now I get another error OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/pi/content/chrome-linux64/chrome', but that is another issue.

Revert to a previous version of selenium
pip install selenium==4.26.1
